# Create a datetime information combining row and column

Tags: python, datetime

I need to transform a database that has year in one column (called "ANO") and month in 12 other columns (from Jan to Dec and a Total). The problem is that i need the year value from each row to transform the year+ the month into a series.

To make the dataset I used this code (i need the value for each row in the second column and for the month the last columns named JAN, FEV,...):

```
    url = 'https://www.gov.br/anp/pt-br/centrais-de-conteudo/dados-abertos/arquivos/arquivos-producao-de-biocombustiveis/producao-biodiesel-m3-2005-2020.csv/@@download/file/producao-biodiesel-m3-2005-2020.csv'
with requests.Session() as s:
    download = s.get(url)
    decoded_content = download.content.decode('utf-8')
    cr = csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter=';')
    my_list = list(cr)
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list[1:1505], columns=my_list[0])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onclC.png)

Answer (score 0):

i tried to find a better format for your data, but probably I failed to understand what you wanted to do - maybe you can make an example of what you are aiming for?. I hope this helps nevertheless.

```
years = set(df["ANO"])
months = ["JAN", "FEV", "MAR", "ABR", "MAI", "JUN", "JUL", "AGO", "SET", "OUT", "NOV", "DEZ"]

biodisel_per_month = dict()
for year in years:
    biodisel_per_month[year] = dict()
    for month in months:
        all_rows_of_month = df.loc[df['ANO'] == year][month] # select all rows of the year and month
        all_rows_of_month = all_rows_of_month.str.replace(',','.') # To make conversion possible
        all_rows_of_month[all_rows_of_month == ""] = 0 # Replace empty fields with 0
        all_rows_of_month = all_rows_of_month.astype(float) # Convert strings to float
        sum_of_biodisel_in_month = sum(all_rows_of_month)
        biodisel_per_month[year][month] = sum_of_biodisel_in_month

pd.DataFrame(biodisel_per_month)
```